# What can be done if messenger changes messages I have sent without my agreement?

Tags: privacy

I'm using one popular messenger app. I'm from Ukraine, but the messenger is registered in the UK. One year ago I sent a poll to one private group (i.e. people can join it only by invitation given by group admins). Now I see that the poll's question and answers have changed to another. I have screenshots of what I have sent one year ago and what is in the group instead of that message now. That messenger doesn't have the ability to change poll data after sending it, so it couldn't be me or someone with access to my account. The poll was about drugs, now it's about Russian tea, so I think it is the messenger's support who changed my poll due to a possible violation of their policy. Also, messenger support does not reply to messages for years, so most likely they won't explain the situation from their point of view. Now, I have several questions:

1. Isn't reading messages by messenger support without permission of group administration or court illegal?
2. The new text of the poll is still accessible in the group and it is signed by my name. If someone will check that message now, he will probably think that the poll is written by me, but it isn't. So, isn't changing messages sent by me without asking or even notifying me illegal?
3. If the things I have listed above are illegal, is there's anything I can do? Preferably non-judicial way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It isn't necessarily illegal to modify messages on a messaging platform owned by a private organization. This is probably covered in the Terms of Service (ToS) that you agreed to when you created an account. It also isn't illegal for them to read your messages, analyze them, or even monetize them if it is within the agreed upon ToS.
2. Again, this isn't necessarily illegal. Private services have a lot more ability to change things than say a governmental unit. If the messenger service were owned by the UK government, this may be different.
3. They are not illegal, but you may want to check the Terms of Service. If you were harmed financially, you may be able to sue, but by your own admission the original post may be against the ToS which means they are within their rights to modify or remove it.

You can't really force them to do anything in this case since what they did isn't illegal, possibly save the exception of deleting your personal data (GPDR) which may or may not delete the original post, but would certainly remove your name from it (and everything else on the service).

Comment: The OP is in the Ukraine and not subject to GDPR.

Comment: @DaleM But the company is in the UK and is subject to GPDR... Under GPDR, any UK/EU company established in the UK/EU must apply GPDR to all of its data, whether or not that person (data subject) is in the UK/EU or not.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response. Can I ask one more question: what if they haven't stated in the ToS that drug discussion isn't allowed or/and that they have the right to edit messages that violate ToS?

Comment: It still isn't *illegal*, but you probably won't be successful in "forcing" them to do anything other than update the ToS and/or ban you from the service. It's the same way that Facebook or Twitter can't violate your rights by censoring you... It may be different if this were a government run platform, but I'm guessing this is a private enterprise.